# Anko view from class

Tags: android, kotlin, anko

I have implemented a class which does various api-request, my idea was that every instance of the class has a method to create a view to have tile like interface.

My problem is i don't know how this should be implemented in a good way.

What is the prefered way doing this using Anko and Kotlin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anko has great [documentation about that case](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-Layouts#is-it-extensible) (But who read docs, yeah?)

> Let's say, `CustomView` is your custom `View` class name, and
>   `customView` is what you want to write in the DSL.
>
> If you only plan to use your custom `View` in the DSL surrounded by
>   some other `View`:
>
> ```
> inline fun ViewManager.customView(theme: Int = 0) = customView(theme) {}
> inline fun ViewManager.customView(theme: Int = 0, init: CustomView.() -> Unit) = ankoView({ CustomView(it) }, theme, init)
> ```
>
> So now you can write this:
>
> ```
> frameLayout {
>     customView()
> }
> ```
>
> …or this (see the UI wrapper chapter):
>
> ```
> UI {
>     customView()
> }
> ```
>
> But if you want to use your view as a top-level widget without a UI
>   wrapper inside `Activity`, add this as well:
>
> ```
> inline fun Activity.customView(theme: Int = 0) = customView(theme) {}
> inline fun Activity.customView(theme: Int = 0, init: CustomView.() -> Unit) = ankoView({ CustomView(it) }, theme, init)
> ```

Example (that's just how I would use it, you may choose different approach):

```
class YourAwesomeButton: Button() {
    /* ... */ 
    fun makeThisButtonAwesome() {/* ... */}
}

/** This lines may be in any file of the project, but better to put them right under the button class */
inline fun ViewManager.yourAwesomeButton(theme: Int = 0) = yourAwesomeButton(theme) {}
inline fun ViewManager.yourAwesomeButton(theme: Int = 0, init: CustomView.() -> Unit) = 
    ankoView({ YourAwesomeButton(it) }, theme, init)
```

In another file:

```
class YourAwesomeActivity: Activity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState)
        relativeLayout(R.style.YourAwesomeAppTheme) {
            yourAwesomeButton(R.style.YourAwesomeAppTheme) {
                makeThisButtonAwesome()
            }.lparams {
                centerInParent()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have read this part of the documentation, but to me it is still unclear on how to use this code snippets. Do you have an example?

Comment: @aul12 added an example

Comment: Hmm, that link to the documentation is dead. It seems the [docs](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/tree/master/doc) in the Anko repo have been replaced by three png images that are not particularly useful...